# Only three event listeners

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the size of each *div* element once you mouse over them.  Once you mouse out I need them to return back to the original size.  After each *div* element is clicked I want them to disappear.  I believe all of those are working.  The issue I have is I feel I don't need 15 event listeners.  Is there a way I could just use three events listeners?

```js
var oneRef = document.getElementById("one");
oneRef.addEventListener('mouseover', bigger);
oneRef.addEventListener('mouseout', smaller);
oneRef.removeEventListener("click", remove);

var oneRef = document.getElementById("two");
oneRef.addEventListener('mouseover', bigger);
oneRef.addEventListener('mouseout', smaller);
oneRef.removeEventListener("click", remove);

var oneRef = document.getElementById("three");
oneRef.addEventListener('mouseover', bigger);
oneRef.addEventListener('mouseout', smaller);
oneRef.removeEventListener("click", remove);

var oneRef = document.getElementById("four");
oneRef.addEventListener('mouseover', bigger);
oneRef.addEventListener('mouseout', smaller);
oneRef.removeEventListener("click", remove);

var oneRef = document.getElementById("five");
oneRef.addEventListener('mouseover', bigger);
oneRef.addEventListener('mouseout', smaller);
oneRef.removeEventListener("click", remove);



function bigger(event) {

  event.target.style.height = "200px";
  event.target.style.width = "200px";

}

function smaller(event) {

  event.target.style.height = "100px";
  event.target.style.width = "100px";

}

function remove(event) {

  var elem = document.getElementById("one");
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#one {
  background-color: #11cd06;
}

#two {
  background-color: #a0f06c;
}

#three {
  background-color: #8df000;
}

#four {
  background-color: #0e5400;
}

#five {
  background-color: #538413;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" onclick="remove()"></div>
<div id="two" onclick="remove()"></div>
<div id="three" onclick="remove()"></div>
<div id="four" onclick="remove()"></div>
<div id="five" onclick="remove()"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function:

```
function addListeners(target) {
    target.addEventListener('mouseover', bigger);
    target.addEventListener('mouseout', smaller);
    target.removeEventListener("click", remove);    
}
```

Then, just call addListeners on all 5 of the items by id:

```
addListeners(oneRef);
addListeners(twoRef);
addListeners(threeRef);
addListeners(fourRef);
addListeners(fiveRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that could work for any number of *div* elements would be to iterate through all *div* elements with [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control), where the callback to *.forEach()* adds the event listeners for *mouseover* and *mouseout*.

Additionally, instead of adding the *click* handler to each *div* element, use a generic click handler on the entire DOM. Then when the target of the click event is a *div* element, remove it (Note: if other other *div* elements that are added to the page that shouldn't be removed on click, apply a class attribute and check if the class name exists with [classList.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)).

```js
//ensure DOM has loaded before interacting with it
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //observe click events 
  document.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
    if (clickEvent.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'DIV') {
      clickEvent.target.remove();
    }
  });
  document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(divElement) {
    divElement.addEventListener('mouseover', bigger);
    divElement.addEventListener('mouseout', smaller);
  });
});

function bigger(event) {

  event.target.style.height = "200px";
  event.target.style.width = "200px";

}

function smaller(event) {

  event.target.style.height = "100px";
  event.target.style.width = "100px";

}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#one {
  background-color: #11cd06;
}

#two {
  background-color: #a0f06c;
}

#three {
  background-color: #8df000;
}

#four {
  background-color: #0e5400;
}

#five {
  background-color: #538413;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="five"></div>
```